# awk string search and replace with appended incremented number

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I am having some trouble finding string (topic-link) and then appending an incremented number using awk.

I have the following html file that is all one line:

```
<a class="topic-link" href="test.com/topic/gastrointestinal">Gastrointestinal</a>, <a class="topic-link" href="test.com/topic/nutrition">Nutrition</a>, <a class="topic-link" href="test.com/topic/weight-gain">Weight Gain</a> </p>
```

Using awk I am trying to obtain:

```
<a class="topic-link1" href="test.com/topic/gastrointestinal">Gastrointestinal</a>, <a class="topic-link2" href="test.com/topic/nutrition">Nutrition</a>, <a class="topic-link3" href="test.com/topic/weight-gain">Weight Gain</a> </p>
```

I am running the following:

```
awk '{gsub("topic-link","topic-link"++i)}1' input file > output file
```

The problem is that the results will be as follows:

```
<a class="topic-link1" href="test.com/topic/gastrointestinal">Gastrointestinal</a>, <a class="topic-link1" href="test.com/topic/nutrition">Nutrition</a>, <a class="topic-link1" href="test.com/topic/weight-gain">Weight Gain</a> </p>
```

The solution I have come up with will only work correctly if the instances of "topic-link" are on separate lines and as such I am stuck.

Please tell me I am missing something very obvious here or if you have any suggestions for an alternative approach.

Thanks!

Rylan

Answer (score 1):

Your gsub() is only called once so i is only incremented once. You need a loop:

```
$ awk '{i=0; while(sub(/topic-link"/,"topic-link"++i"\""));} 1' file
<a class="topic-link1" href="test.com/topic/gastrointestinal">Gastrointestinal</a>, <a class="topic-link2" href="test.com/topic/nutrition">Nutrition</a>, <a class="topic-link3" href="test.com/topic/weight-gain">Weight Gain</a> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks Ed this did the trick. I figured I needed a loop but didn't know the proper syntax / procedure to do so with awk. I would say I need to brush up on my google / stackoverflow search fu moving forward.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend you leave the question open for several more hours to see if you get an answer you prefer and THEN click on the check mark next to the answer you think best solves your problem to close the question out. Also - the best way to learn how to manipulate text in general is to read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.